# Clarification of the proof that if $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ then $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[a,b]$

Tags: analysis

Claim: If $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ then $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[a,b]$.

Proof: Suppose that $f$ is not uniformly continuous on $[a,b]$, then there exists $\epsilon > 0 $ such that for each  $\delta > 0$ there must exist $x,y \in [a,b]$ such that $|x-y| < \delta$ and $|f(x)-f(y)| \geq \epsilon$ . 
 Thus for each $n \in \Bbb N$ there exists $x_n,y_n$ such that $|x_n-y_n| < \frac {1} {n}$, and By B-W, $x_n$ has a subsequence $x_{n_k}$ with limit $x_o$ that belongs to $[a,b]$. 
 Now here is where I am confused, the author next states that "Clearly we also have $x_0 $ is the limit of the sub-sequence $y_{n_k}$". Are $x_n$ and $y_n$ not potentially different sequences? Why would the same indexes chosen to form a sub-sequence give the same convergent value.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli thanks edited.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli I don't understand your possible duplicate reference, are these not two sub-sequences of potentially different sequences $x_n$ and $y_n$ ??

Comment: Good point. Vote retracted. @jamesdickens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every $c>0$, there exists $k_0$ such that $k>k_0$ implies that $|x_0-x_{n_k}|<c/2$, we choose $k'_0>k_0$ such that ${1\over n_{k'_0}}<c/2$. Let $k>k'_0$, $|x_0-y_{n_k}|\leq |x_0-x_{n_k}|+|x_{n_k}-y_{n_k}|\leq |x_0-x_{n_k}|+{1\over n_k}<c/2+c/2<c.$

Comment: This is a great answer, but why instinctually should I know this to be true.

Comment: Instinctively? One (sub)sequence converges, and the other is tailgating it (the difference between the two sequence goes to zero). If a car is chasing another one, getting closer and closer, and the first ends up in Toronto, then the second car also is in Toronto.

Answer (score 0):

Is it true perhaps that

$\lim_{k\to \infty}|x_{n_k}-y_{n_k}| = \lim_{k\to \infty} \frac {1}{n_k} = 0$ 
thus lim $ x_{n_k} = $lim $ y_{n_k}$ ? But does this not suppose that lim$ y_{n_k}$ exists.